# Double precision number of months between dates postgres

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, double, date-difference

Is it possible to calculate the number of months between two dates as a double precision instead of an integer? For example, difference between `2016-05-04` and `2015-03-21` would be something like `13.42` or `13.43` months?

Comment: .42 or .43 of **which** month?

Comment: I don't particularly care, it could be 13 days out of 30 or 31 or 29 or 28. As long as it's integer number of months + approximate fraction of a quantity that's roughly a month I'm satisfied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to calculate something like that, and you'll get varying results depending on the rules you use for calculating.

The following way gives you a number of 12ths of a year for a given period between two dates:

```
select (date'2016-05-04' - date'2015-03-21') / 365.0 * 12
```

The above results in 13.48.

The following way gives a perhaps more accurate number (13.47), although much more complicated, and resulting in a minimal difference:

```
select extract('years' from age) * 12 + extract('months' from age) + extract('days' from age) / 30
from (select age('2016-05-04'::timestamp, '2015-03-21'::timestamp)) a
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are interested in exact calculation, I wrote the following function to calculate the difference between two dates in months, including the fractional part:

```
CREATE FUNCTION
  MONTH_FRACTION(
      from_date DATE
    , to_date DATE
  )

  RETURNS REAL

  AS
    $$
      WITH
          aux_1 AS (  -- Auxiliary table
            SELECT
                AGE(to_date, from_date) AS duration
          )

        , aux_2 AS (  -- Auxiliary table
            SELECT
                (from_date + DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', duration))::DATE AS to_date_floor
              , (from_date + DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', duration + INTERVAL '1 MONTH'))::DATE AS to_date_ceil
            FROM
              aux_1
          )

      SELECT
        CASE WHEN
          to_date >= from_date
        THEN
          (12 * EXTRACT(YEAR FROM duration) + EXTRACT(MONTH FROM duration) + (to_date - to_date_floor)::REAL / (to_date_ceil - to_date_floor)::REAL)::REAL
        ELSE
          NULL
        END

      FROM
        aux_1, aux_2
    $$

  LANGUAGE SQL
  IMMUTABLE
  RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT;
```